# How to add filter on HTML table on google sheet appscipt web app?

Tags: google-sheets, web-applications, autofilter

EDIT!!: I want to show all the data of each row containing Yes.

Please help, I have a problem on adding a filter to table. There is a Yes and No answer but I only want to display all the Yes on the column. [this is the column i want to be filtered with only yes value, the value being displayed is from google sheet.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rTtL.png)  [this the column from google sheet where the data is being pulled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3ZsI.png)

This is the code I used for displaying data on table
[please see attached photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPf4A.png)